# SELECT multiple discrete records from a set like with LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a query

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
ORDER BY id
```

And I want the 1st, 5th, 100th, 250th result, etc.

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 5, 1
```

Gives you the 5th. And I could run a similar query N times. But, how can I do it more elegantly in only one query?

Something like this (which doesn't work) would be amazing!

```
 LIMIT 1, 5, 100, 250
```

Comment: Maybe make it about 1,3,5,7 and 11, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: both answers are good and i upvoted both, but i gave the check to the old school. but if u r using 5.8 u might reconsider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using a variable for MySQL >= 5.x.x

```
SELECT z.*
FROM (
    SELECT *, @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number
    FROM foo, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
    ORDER BY pkey
) AS z
WHERE row_number IN (1, 5, 100, 250);
```

Here the variable is declared as a table `t`. `@row_number` will be incremented by 1 for each row which can then be filtered using `WHERE` clause.

Comment: the inner SQL really need to have a ORDER BY as SQL is **orderless** by ANSI/ISO SQL standards..

Comment: *"You can achieve it by using a variable for MySQL 5.x.x"* By the way MySQL 8 also supports user variables it's from around MySQL 5.1 and up where MySQL supports it..

Comment: Yes, thought to put as an alternative answer to Lukasz where I missed adding >= to the version number. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

One way would be [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql/46753800#46753800)(MySQL 8.0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS rn FROM foo) sub
WHERE rn IN (1, 5, 100, 250)
ORDER BY rn;
```